# Elliptic Curve Encryption Algorithm:ES256, Curve: P-256 Format representations

Tags: ecc

Can I please get some help in understanding the representation/connection between the issuer key structure, such as the one here:

```
{
    "kty": "EC",
    "d": "6RDoFJrbnJ9WG0Y1CVXN0EnxbuQIgRMQfzFVKogbO6c",
    "use": "sig",
    "crv": "P-256",
    "x": "eIA4ZrdR7IOzYRqLER9_JIkfQCAeo1QI3VCEB7KaIow",
    "y": "WKPa365UL5KRw6OJJsZ3R_qFGQXCHg6eJe5Nzw526uQ",
    "alg": "ES256"
}
```

And the actual elliptic curve Curve25519 which is supposed to satisfy the equation:
y^2 = x^3+486662x^2+x

Are the x and y above related to the x and y which I see in this equation? If so, in what way exactly? And how is the private key "d" connected to all this? How does the x+y on the curve related to the "d"? And the kid (key-id)? which is not even shown above.
Why are they all 43 bytes long?

And what format are above represented in?

Also: I notice the QR code is 1776 bytes long:

```
shc:/56762909510950603511292437..............656
```

Which gets translated to a "numeric" code of length 888:

```
eyJ7aXAiOiKERUYiLREhbGciOiJFUzI1Ni.......xpW
```

(How does one convert it as such?)

which in turn gets to:

```
{"zip":"DEF","alg":"ES256","kid":"Nlewb7pUrU_f0tghYKc88uXM9U8en1gBu88rlufPUj7"}
```

And private key in X.509 format looks like this:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MEECAQAwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcEJzAlAgEBBCDpEOgUmtucn1YbRjUJ
Vc3QSfFu5AiBExB/MVUqiBs7pw==
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Why 92 bytes?

They are all related....just trying to understand how they are converted to one another and particularly to the equation of the curve?

Thanks
Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elliptic Curve Cryptography is a complicated subject, and explaining how it works is far beyond the scope of an answer on this board.  But, I'll refer you to [Elliptic Curve Cryptography: a gentle introduction](https://andrea.corbellini.name/2015/05/17/elliptic-curve-cryptography-a-gentle-introduction/) by Andrea Corbellini, which I found to by an excellent source when I was trying to understand how Elliptic Curve Cryptography works, and I think this will point you in the right direction towards answers to most of your questions.

In the key that you posted, `d` is the private key, represented in base64 format:  `6RDoFJrbnJ9WG0Y1CVXN0EnxbuQIgRMQfzFVKogbO6c`, and `"crv": "P-256"` denotes that this is a P256 curve.  The public key is derived from the private key.  To get the public key x and y values, the private key must be multiplied by a 'generator point' using the P256 elliptic curve.  We can find the generator point and the parameters for the P256 elliptic curve here:  https://safecurves.cr.yp.to/equation.html

The author of the article that I referenced above has a python script that does elliptic curve math here:
https://github.com/andreacorbellini/ecc/blob/master/scripts/ecdhe.py  I found this script to be useful in understanding how the math works, and playing with the math.

To see how the public key x and y values in the key that you provided are derived from the private key, we can make a few modifications to Corbellini's script, to use the parameters for the P256 curve, and `6RDoFJrbnJ9WG0Y1CVXN0EnxbuQIgRMQfzFVKogbO6c` as the private key, like so:

```
import collections
import base64

EllipticCurve = collections.namedtuple('EllipticCurve', 'name p a b g n h')

#from https://safecurves.cr.yp.to/field.html:
curve = EllipticCurve(
    'P-256',
    # Field characteristic.
    p=0xffffffff00000001000000000000000000000000ffffffffffffffffffffffff,
    # Curve coefficients.
    a=-3,
    b=41058363725152142129326129780047268409114441015993725554835256314039467401291,
    # Base point.
    g=(0x6b17d1f2e12c4247f8bce6e563a440f277037d812deb33a0f4a13945d898c296,
       0x4fe342e2fe1a7f9b8ee7eb4a7c0f9e162bce33576b315ececbb6406837bf51f5),
    # Subgroup order.
    n=0xffffffff00000000ffffffffffffffffbce6faada7179e84f3b9cac2fc632551,
    # Subgroup cofactor.
    h=1,

)


# Modular arithmetic ##########################################################

def inverse_mod(k, p):
    """Returns the inverse of k modulo p.

    This function returns the only integer x such that (x * k) % p == 1.

    k must be non-zero and p must be a prime.
    """
    if k == 0:
    raise ZeroDivisionError('division by zero')

    if k < 0:
    # k ** -1 = p - (-k) ** -1  (mod p)
    return p - inverse_mod(-k, p)

    # Extended Euclidean algorithm.
    s, old_s = 0, 1
    t, old_t = 1, 0
    r, old_r = p, k

    while r != 0:
    quotient = old_r // r
    old_r, r = r, old_r - quotient * r
    old_s, s = s, old_s - quotient * s
    old_t, t = t, old_t - quotient * t

    gcd, x, y = old_r, old_s, old_t

    assert gcd == 1
    assert (k * x) % p == 1

    return x % p


# Functions that work on curve points #########################################

def is_on_curve(point):
    """Returns True if the given point lies on the elliptic curve."""
    if point is None:
    # None represents the point at infinity.
    return True

    x, y = point

    return (y * y - x * x * x - curve.a * x - curve.b) % curve.p == 0


def point_neg(point):
    """Returns -point."""
    assert is_on_curve(point)

    if point is None:
    # -0 = 0
    return None

    x, y = point
    result = (x, -y % curve.p)

    assert is_on_curve(result)

    return result


def point_add(point1, point2):
    """Returns the result of point1 + point2 according to the group law."""
    assert is_on_curve(point1)
    assert is_on_curve(point2)

    if point1 is None:
    # 0 + point2 = point2
    return point2
    if point2 is None:
    # point1 + 0 = point1
    return point1

    x1, y1 = point1
    x2, y2 = point2

    if x1 == x2 and y1 != y2:
    # point1 + (-point1) = 0
    return None

    if x1 == x2:
    # This is the case point1 == point2.
    m = (3 * x1 * x1 + curve.a) * inverse_mod(2 * y1, curve.p)
    else:
    # This is the case point1 != point2.
    m = (y1 - y2) * inverse_mod(x1 - x2, curve.p)

    x3 = m * m - x1 - x2
    y3 = y1 + m * (x3 - x1)
    result = (x3 % curve.p,
          -y3 % curve.p)

    assert is_on_curve(result)

    return result


def scalar_mult(k, point):
    """Returns k * point computed using the double and point_add algorithm."""
    assert is_on_curve(point)

    if k % curve.n == 0 or point is None:
    return None

    if k < 0:
    # k * point = -k * (-point)
    return scalar_mult(-k, point_neg(point))

    result = None
    addend = point

    while k:
    if k & 1:
        # Add.
        result = point_add(result, addend)

    # Double.
    addend = point_add(addend, addend)

    k >>= 1

    assert is_on_curve(result)

    return result


private_key_hex='6RDoFJrbnJ9WG0Y1CVXN0EnxbuQIgRMQfzFVKogbO6c='
private_key=int.from_bytes(base64.b64decode(private_key_hex), 'big')

public_key = scalar_mult(private_key, curve.g)
(public_key_x, public_key_y)=public_key

print("private key:", base64.b64encode(private_key.to_bytes(32,'big')))
print("public key x:", base64.b64encode(public_key_x.to_bytes(32,'big')))
print("public key y:", base64.b64encode(public_key_y.to_bytes(32,'big')))
```

Running this script produces:

```
private key: b'6RDoFJrbnJ9WG0Y1CVXN0EnxbuQIgRMQfzFVKogbO6c='
public key x: b'eIA4ZrdR7IOzYRqLER9/JIkfQCAeo1QI3VCEB7KaIow='
public key y: b'WKPa365UL5KRw6OJJsZ3R/qFGQXCHg6eJe5Nzw526uQ='
```

As you can see, the public key x and y values produced by the script match those in the key that you posted.  I hope this helps.

Comment: This is excellent, thanks @mti2935! a couple of things: 1)If I want to use the equation y^2 = x^3+486662x^2+x, then I assume this code can be modified as such? 2) So you used the private key I gave to generate both x and y? (funny, I had randomized it, still worked?)  3) If I only had the x and y, is there a code to go through all combos (given the above equation) to be able to guess the private key? Would the given equation not reduce the number of possibilities?

Comment: Also shouldn't the x and y values satisfy that math equation outright? I mean the given ones are in base64, they are not even a pair of points. How are they represented as a pair of points like x(p1,p2) and y(p3,p4) in order for us to find the 3rd point of cross on that curve, the drop it vertically down to hit the curve again in order to arrive at "x+y" ? I just don't see the graphical representation for the above base64 characters.

Comment: @Steve, no problem.  1) Those are the parameters for the Curve25519 EC curve.  You can find those and the generator point at  https://safecurves.cr.yp.to/equation.html. To use Curve25519 instead of P256, just modify the values in the script (near the top).  2) Usually the private key is generated randomly (it's a 256-bit integer), then the public key (which consists of an x and y value) is derived from the private key.  I just used the private key that you posted (instead of a random one) to show how the public key that you posted is derived from that private key.

Comment: 3)  **NO!!!***  That's the whole point of asymmetric cryptography.  The public key is easy to derive from the private key.  But, it is very hard (practically impossible) to do the opposite and derive the private key from the public key.  If this were possible, then other other people could decrypt messages that were encrypted with your public key, or impersonate you by making digital signatures with your private key,  or spend all your bitcoins.

Comment: WRT `Also shouldn't the x and y values satisfy that math equation outright? `: yes, but you have to use EC math.  See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/233099/validating-an-ed25519-public-ke for a similar question.  I modified the program to print private_key, public_key_x, public_key_y  in base64 format so that it would match what you posted.  But, these are just integers, you can print them as is to see them in decimal format.

Comment: oh ok that link is good...yes i need to see the connection between the x, y, the curve

Comment: So in the code you generated the public keys based on the private one i provided? I think you added an "=" at the end...was that an oversight? And you used a different algo NIST P-256, not Curve25519 - so i can change that.  I hope the link will explain the points on the curve. I like to plot the graph and place the points on it, and see if they add correct on the chart. assume i can do that.    As well your code is having indentation issues in python when I try to run, i need to see why.  There's a reindent.py code i think i can use to correct

Comment: @Steve The '=' is just base64 padding.  Base64 encoded strings are supposed to have a length that is a multiple of 4, and python complains if they are not.  I believe the keys that you posted are based on the P256 curve (`"crv": "P-256"`).  If not, then there would be no way that the public key would have come out the same as the one you posted.  Sorry about the indentation issues.  Sometimes the indents get mangled when copying and pasting into SE.  https://blog.cloudflare.com/a-relatively-easy-to-understand-primer-on-elliptic-curve-cryptography/ is also good.

Answer (score 1):

While mti gave you a good explanation of the substance, to fill some of the superfical gaps:

The *representation*

```
{
    "kty": "EC",
    "d": "6RDoFJrbnJ9WG0Y1CVXN0EnxbuQIgRMQfzFVKogbO6c",
    "use": "sig",
    "crv": "P-256",
    "x": "eIA4ZrdR7IOzYRqLER9_JIkfQCAeo1QI3VCEB7KaIow",
    "y": "WKPa365UL5KRw6OJJsZ3R_qFGQXCHg6eJe5Nzw526uQ",
    "alg": "ES256"
}
```

is JWK (JSON Web Key) generally defined in [rfc7517](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7517) based on JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) defined in [rfc7159](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7159) which in turn is based on JavaScript (now evolved into ECMAScript). Particular key types are defined in [rfc7518](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7518) including X9/NIST/Weierstrass-form EC in 6.2.
The keys for the Montgomery-form key-agreement algorithms Bernstein originally named curve25519 and curve448, now renamed X or sometimes XDH to separate them from the signature algorthms Ed25519[ph] and Ed448[ph] based on transforms of the same curves, are defined in [rfc8037](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8037.html).

Your reference to an 'issuer' key suggests you really want not X25519 but the signature algorithm Ed25519, which uses a different Edwards-form equation that is not listed in https://safecurves.cr.yp.to/equation.html but is in [rfc8032 section 5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8032#section-5.1) together with its related but different computation.

But what you call 'X.509' format

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MEECAQAwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcEJzAlAgEBBCDpEOgUmtucn1YbRjUJ
Vc3QSfFu5AiBExB/MVUqiBs7pw==
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

is not X.509 (which concerns only public keys), although it is a format used by *some* (not all) the things that concurrently use X.509 (or its Internet profile PKIX) for public-key management. Specifically it is a PEM-style or 'textual' format defined in [rfc7468 section 2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7468#section-2) which 'armors' in base64 with labels an ASN.1 (binary) structure, in this case [(section 10)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7468#section-10) a private key defined by PKCS8 now available as [rfc5208](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5208). PKCS8 is a generic structure that embeds algorithm-specific data, which for X9/NISTian EC is SEC1 also available as [rfc5915](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5915).

Decoding this with `openssl` (which does base64 and ASN.1 in a foop) shows the structure:

```
$ openssl asn1parse -i
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MEECAQAwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcEJzAlAgEBBCDpEOgUmtucn1YbRjUJ
Vc3QSfFu5AiBExB/MVUqiBs7pw==
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
    0:d=0  hl=2 l=  65 cons: SEQUENCE
    2:d=1  hl=2 l=   1 prim:  INTEGER           :00
    5:d=1  hl=2 l=  19 cons:  SEQUENCE
    7:d=2  hl=2 l=   7 prim:   OBJECT            :id-ecPublicKey
   16:d=2  hl=2 l=   8 prim:   OBJECT            :prime256v1
   26:d=1  hl=2 l=  39 prim:  OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:30250201010420E910E8149ADB9C9F561B46350955CDD049F16EE4088113107F31552A881B3BA7
$ openssl asn1parse -i -strparse 26   # the algorithm-specific part
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MEECAQAwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcEJzAlAgEBBCDpEOgUmtucn1YbRjUJ
Vc3QSfFu5AiBExB/MVUqiBs7pw==
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
    0:d=0  hl=2 l=  37 cons: SEQUENCE
    2:d=1  hl=2 l=   1 prim:  INTEGER           :01
    5:d=1  hl=2 l=  32 prim:  OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:E910E8149ADB9C9F561B46350955CDD049F16EE4088113107F31552A881B3BA7
```

As you can see that last and only 'real' value in the algorithm-specific data is the same value produced by base64-decoding the d in your JWK:

```
$ <<<"6RDoFJrbnJ9WG0Y1CVXN0EnxbuQIgRMQfzFVKogbO6c=" openssl base64 -d | xxd -p -c32
e910e8149adb9c9f561b46350955cdd049f16ee4088113107f31552a881b3ba7
```

Comment: +1 Nice answer, especially the part about `openssl asn1parse`.

Comment: Thx Dave! Let me read through this carefully once i get some time and get back to you if any questions.

Comment: Ok Have read though all above but still can't see 2 simple things please: 1-From above What can I plug into y^2 = x^3+486662x^2+x to see that the points lie on that curve? and 2-If I do not have a private key and only public key, what code can I run on a random private key so I can compare the output to the public key to see if a match is made? How many bytes to I have to cycle through?  and lastly: 3-mti2935, can you please send me a file attachment of that code as I cannot run it due to indents. Thanks

Comment: Steve: y^2=x^3+486662x^2+x is the _Montgomery_ form used in curve25519-now-X[DH]25519. The key you posted is for a different curve (usually called P-256) that uses a different form (Weierstrass), and you can't directly use Weierstrass code on Montgomery data or vice versa. However, if you have only the public key in _either_ scheme you can't find the private key during the existence of the Earth, and probably the universe; that's what makes these schemes secure enough for people to use. Meta: normally you need to use atsign (@) to notify anyone other than the post author.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: Your thoughts on the Pollard Rho algorithm/attack?

Comment: @mti2935: put the code through an online beautifier to fix the indents. When I run it now it just spins and hangs. Isn't it supposed to be quick run? I literally have to ^C out of it after 1 min.

Comment: @Steve  I pasted the code at pastebin at https://pastebin.com/CbFtGSci.  It runs instantly when I run it on my system.

Comment: Also, in addition to what @dave_thompson_085 mentioned about the time that it would take to crack a 256-bit key - you would also have a very high electric bill.  See the answer bi ir01 at  https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1145/how-much-would-it-cost-in-u-s-dollars-to-brute-force-a-256-bit-key-in-a-year

Comment: @Steve: Pollard Rho is a generic attack, equal for all dlog methods. That's why the curves we use, including P-256 and 25519, are chosen to make it infeasible -- at least with classical computers. Quantum, if it ever works, probably breaks _all_ now-common asymmetric schemes, which is why NIST/NSA is working on finding and standardizing post-quantum schemes

Comment: @mti2935: unfortunately (as Steve points out) EC 256bit doesn't require 256bit bruteforce; it actually requires about 2^128 which is why I only claimed Earth and not (definitely) the universe.

Comment: @mti2935: Yeah thanks I fixed it already and works fine. Got the original source (zip) then compared against yours and updated it. Re: Electricity Bill!? Naaaah, CMOS uses zilch.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: [Rho](https://github.com/sandeshc/pollard-rho-attack) that says: "python pollardRhoAttack.py <N> <B> where, N is the large prime and B is the bound"  Now using the above code, what is my N and B that i need to feed into this?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: Also can we not convert The P-256 curve  to short Weierstrass form? Thereby simplifying it for attack?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks for the clarification that it's 2^128, not 2^256.  Steve, for your (1) above, use the script that I posed at https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/233099/validating-an-ed25519-public-key.  For (2) use the script that you just got working, and give it the random private key, and see if the resulting public key matches the one that you have.

Comment: @Steve, re. electric bill:   The physical minimum amount of energy needed to set or clear one bit (regardless of what technology is used, CMOS or otherwise) is 4.4⋅10^−16 ergs (see link I posted above).  If iterating through all 2^128 permutations required us to just flip one bit each (we know it would require much more than that), then this would consume 1.5⋅10^23 ergs. [(2^128) * (4.4⋅10^−16) = 1.5⋅10^23].  One kilowatt-hour is 3.6⋅10^13 ergs, so this equates to 4.2 billion kilowatt-hours [1.5⋅10^23 / 3.6⋅10^13 = 4.2⋅10^9].  At $0.10 / KWH, your bill would be $420M!

Comment: @Steve: P-256 (like all X9/Certicom/NIST curves) _is_ in Weierstrass form, as I indicated days ago and as shown on the Bernstein page you were already linked to, plus Rho is as I said generic and is neither helped nor hindered at all by the curve form.

Comment: Thanks @mti2935, so I see the link that verifies if 2 points are on the curve. What's surprising is that it does not pass them in as INT but rather HEX. Shouldn't they be evaluated as INTs?

Comment: Can either of you answer my question above (6th previous comment to this) please on the Rho Link I sent and how to use that code? I don't get the 2 inputs N and B. I want to see how that relates to the code above in the post please. Thanks.

Comment: @Steve, yes they are just integers, so they can be represented either in hexadecimal form or in decimal form.  In python, `x=0xbcb1` is equivalent to `x=48305`.

Comment: @Steve re. Rho, the script that you linked to (pollardRhoAttack.py) is for factoring large numbers that are the product of two prime numbers.  This might be of use with RSA cryptography for cracking RSA private keys (where the private key is made up of two large prime numbers, and the public key is the product of these two primes), but this does not apply in Elliptic Curve cryptography.

Comment: @mti2935: Disagree. See these 2 references of Rho on Elliptic: [one](http://koclab.cs.ucsb.edu/teaching/ecc/project/2015Projects/Blumenfeld-Presentation.pdf) and [two](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/35471943.pdf) Unless you guys know of another Rho script which is more tailored for Elliptic?

Comment: @Steve The two papers that you linked to above describe different algorithms than the one implemented in the pollardRhoAttack.py that you linked to on Github.

Comment: @mti2935: doesn't matter. Point being Rho can be used for Elliptic.